# Does running away from pokemon while chaining stop the chain?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Many have said you need a pokemon with a lot of pp-- I'm assuming its because you can't,  but I just legit found a shiny horsea while looking for timid or modest and running away from claunchers.

Do you have to fight or catch all of the pokemon you want to continue the chain? I just want to know how rare this horsea is. Its hasty nature, icyww.